# VBScript --Delete folder contents and place a file

Tags: vbscript

Any help would be appreciated. I would like to delete the contents of a folder and place a file based on criteria (Set Name and a variable date--today). I tried cobbling something together...but even I see the logic is getting skewy as I chase my own tail. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Set FSO1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = FSO1.GetFolder("C:Docs\Template")

for each f in folder.files
On Error Resume Next
name = f.name
f.Delete True
On error GoTo 0
Next

MyDate = Replace(Date,"/","-")
Const src = "C:\Docs\Blah"
Const dst = "C:\Docs\Template"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For each f In FSO.GetFolder(src).Files
If FSO.GetFileName(f.name) = "Bluhdeblah_" & Mydate & ".xlsm"
Then FSO.CopyFile src, "C:\Docs\Template", True

End If

Set FSO = Nothing
Set FSO1 = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues here and there. Try below (untested) and understand the flow of it:

```
Const src = "C:\Docs\Blah\" ' Note "\" is added here
Const dst = "C:\Docs\Template\"
UpdateFolder

Sub UpdateFolder()
    Dim oFSO, oFile, sFile
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ' Delete Existing Files
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(dst).Files
        oFile.Delete
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' Copy updated file if found in src to dst
    sFile = src & "Bluhdeblah_" & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yy") & ".xlsm"
    If oFSO.FileExists(sFile) Then oFSO.copyfile sFile, dst, True
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The first half worked great! The second half, not as much. Would it help to note that the file with today's date would also be the most recently modified? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Can add a line `Wscript.Echo "sFile: " & sFile` just below **sFile** is assigned and compare the output is what the file you have? I have a hunch that the Date format (D/M/YYYY vs M/D/YYYY) is different so the file is not found.

Comment: the actual date field is mm/dd/yy which I think is the problem.

Comment: I have updated the code to utilise `Format()`. Change to whatever format you are using and have another go.